# Player cannot double jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial on YouTube and everything is working fine until now, except I can only have one jump with this code, any advice ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public float power = 500; 
    public int jumpHeight = 1000; 
    public bool isFalling = false; 
    public int Score;
    public Text SCORE; 
    public GameObject YOUDIED; 
    private int health = 3;
    public GameObject health1; 
    public GameObject health2; 
    public GameObject health3;
    public int Highscore;
    private bool canDoubleJump; 
    private bool jumpOne; 
    private bool jumpTwo;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () { 
        YOUDIED.SetActive(false);
        Highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Highscore", 0);     
        jumpOne = false;   
        jumpTwo = false;    
        canDoubleJump = false;
    }

    void Update() {     
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && health == 0) {
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
            health = 3;
            Application.LoadLevel(0);
        }

        if (health == 3) {
            health1.SetActive (true);
            health2.SetActive (true);
            health3.SetActive (true);
        }

        if (health == 2) {
            health1.SetActive (true);
            health2.SetActive (true);
            health3.SetActive (false);
        }

        if (health == 1) {
            health1.SetActive (true);
            health2.SetActive (false);
            health3.SetActive (false);
        }

        if (health == 0) {
            health1.SetActive (false);
            health2.SetActive (false);
            health3.SetActive (false);
        }

        if (health <= 0) {
            YOUDIED.SetActive (true);
            Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
        }

        SCORE.text = "Score " + Score;

        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * power * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isFalling == false) {
            jumpOne = true;
            canDoubleJump = true;
            isFalling = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isFalling == true && canDoubleJump == true) {
            jumpTwo = true;
            canDoubleJump = false;
        }

     }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        if (jumpOne == true) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight);
            jumpOne = false;
        }

        if (jumpTwo == true) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight);
            jumpTwo = false;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D coll) {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            isFalling = false;
            canDoubleJump = false;
    }

 }

    public void ScorePlus(int NewScore) {
        Score += NewScore;    

        if(Score >= Highscore) {
            Highscore = Score;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Highscore", Highscore);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll) {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Death") {
            health -= 1;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Where are you jumping in there? You need to be clear about what code is not working as expected, and what it is exactly doing now that is not what you want.

Comment: can you please post youtubelink too?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the exceptional bad code from the tutorial in question, is of no pedagogical value whatsoever and the answer to the QA as such could only possibly be relevant to that ephemeral irrelevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
I put an else if statement instead of only an if

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isFalling == false) {
        jumpOne = true;
        canDoubleJump = true;
        isFalling = true;
    }else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isFalling == true && canDoubleJump == true) {
        jumpTwo = true;
        canDoubleJump = false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

canDoubleJump should be set to true here

```
void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D coll) {
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
        isFalling = false;
        canDoubleJump = false;
}
```

also in the first jump you need to set isFalling to true

```
    if (jumpOne == true) {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight);
        jumpOne = false;
        isFalling = true;
    }
```

That should do the trick